# ElasticSearch: Is there a way to get list of tokens or lemma from a text field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with a field with `analyzer` mapping. As per the documentation, `analyzer` will help in the search with stemmed token (and maybe with lemma).

But I am wondering, If I want the list of tokens,lemmas generated by the elasticsearch analyzer, is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is what you are looking for. But you can do this:

```
GET YOU_INDEX_NAME_HERE/_analyze

{
    "analyzer": "ANALYZER_NAME_HERE",
    "text": "This Is a test text for analyze"
}
```

And response will be the list of tokens.

For example for this query:

```
{
    "analyzer": "standard",
    "text": "This Is a test"
}
```

you will get response:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "this",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "is",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "a",
            "start_offset": 8,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "test",
            "start_offset": 10,
            "end_offset": 14,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

More information in [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html)